# LibGdx:Alternatives to ShapeRenderer

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Note: I am new to LibGdx with android.

I am Creating a clone of the famous game Color Switch for practice purposes.

I have used ShapeRenderer for creating the ball and moving circles.
After reading more about ShapeRenderer, I realized it is mostly used for debugging purposes, so I searched for other alternatives to it and I got to know about Pixmaps but I am stuck on how to use it and cannot find any source.

So I want to know if there any other alternatives to ShapeRenderer or any sources for Pixmaps to get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShapeRenderer` is perfectly fine for your use-case. So, unless you have an actual problem with it, there is no need to switch to something else.

The reason that `ShapeRenderer` is primarily used for debugging is because it's limited to basic shapes and colors. In many use-cases this is insufficient and e.g. images (like `.png` files) are used instead. In those cases `SpriteBatch` is typically used to draw the images, which is optimized for (rectangular) images instead of shapes.

A `Pixmap` is the raw image data in CPU memory (RAM), which is practically an interim step between the image on disk (e.g. the `.png` file) and the image (`Texture`) in GPU memory (VRAM). LibGDX handles this interim step for you, so you should never have to deal with `Pixmap` in most use-cases yourself. Manually manipulating a `Pixmap` is very costly operation and worse than using `ShapeRenderer` for your use-case.

Comment: What about Textures should I use Texture for making the ball?

Comment: No, I you prefer ShapeRenderer then just use that. If you'd rather use a Texture then use a Texture ofcourse. For your use-case there is no better reason to use either one over the other.